# how to generate multi module archetype from generated one?

Tags: maven, archetypes

hey everyone, 
I have generated mono module maven project from a generated one by following that link : http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

so i want any one had any idea about the structure of the archetype i must had in my archetype to generate another multi-module archetype from it

Answer (score 0):

You just create your skeleton or model multi module project and then run

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

and in the target/generated-sources/archetype/

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html